# How to Cache DOM Variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/y6o0odtt/)**

Using jquery and highchart.js (+ exporting.js module) I am trying to export the chart by a custom button like  below

```
<button type="button" id="chartpdf" data-chart="chart1" class="pdf-download">PDF</button>
```

While the code is exporting the chart in hard-coded format like this

```
chart1.exportChart({type: "application/pdf"});
```

it is not working  when trying to dynamically get the `chart1` from the element data attribute `data-chart="chart1"`

```
$(document).on("click", ".pdf-download", function(){
     $(this).data('chart').exportChart({type: "application/pdf"});
});
```

can you please let me know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$( CHART ID ).highcharts().exportChart({type: "application/pdf"});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/y6o0odtt/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use highchart.js and I don't know how dose it handle charts.
but in your click listener

```
$(this).data('chart');
```

should return a string 'chart1' (if .data() here is act as jQuery's default method)
and what you did is equal to

```
('chart1').exportChart({type: "application/pdf"});
```

witch is different with

```
chart1.exportChart({type: "application/pdf"});
```

I guess there are something to should do to after you get 'chart1' string 
meaning you should convert this string to your chart1 object.

If there are something I need to know (about highchart.js maybe),please tell me.

EDIT:

according to @Alexander 's answer,
you can do this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".pdf-download", function(){
     var id = $(this).data('chart')
     $("#"+id).highcharts().exportChart({type: "application/pdf"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want to read the object `chart1`.

There are 2 options.

1. Use the `id` of the object.
2. If you need to use your code only, you would need to do the following modifications.

**Change this:**

```
$(function () {
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
```

**to this:**

```
var chart1;
$(function () {
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
```

**Event Handler**

```
$(document).on("click", ".pdf-download", function(){
    window[$(this).attr('data-chart')].exportChart({type: "application/pdf"});
});
```

Hope this helps.